# For what is the folder i18n used for on VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Looking into the https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode source code project, we can find the folder `i18n` (https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/tree/master/i18n) with some files. But there is no explanation about what this folder is for.

For example, looking into some of the files, you can find the notice:

**vscode\i18n\ita\src\vs\platform\keybinding\common\abstractKeybindingService.i18n.json**

```
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *  Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
 *  Licensed under the MIT License. See License.txt in the project root for license information.
 *--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
// Do not edit this file. It is machine generated.
{
    "first.chord": "È stato premuto ({0}). In attesa del secondo tasto...",
    "missing.chord": "La combinazione di tasti ({0}, {1}) non è un comando."
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i18n is always for localization things.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization